# Property json does not exist on type

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I would like to make an http request from my URL, but I have this error :

> json does not exist on type 'Articles'

I don't know why ..

This is my code :

```
    getAllArticles() : Observable<Articles[]>{
    return this.http.get<Articles>(this.urlAllArticles)
      .map(res => {
      return res.json().results.map(item => {
        return new Articles(
        item.id,
        item.titre);
      });
    });
  }
```

The interface IArticles :

```
    export interface IArticles {
  id: number;
  titre: string;
}
```

The class Articles :

```
    class Articles {
  constructor(public id: number,
              public titre: string)
  {
  }
}
```

Result after suggestions :

```
    getAllArticles() : Observable<IArticles>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.urlAllArticles)
      .map(res => {
      return res.results.map(item => {
        return new Articles(
          item.id,
          item.titre
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It sounds like you are using the `httpClient`. The httpClient assumes your response will be json, so you do not need parse with `.json()`. So your code should be `res.results.map(...)`

Comment: read the docs https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @Llai, I have the same error without .json()

Comment: Can you post your `Articles` interface. by doing `this.http.get<Articles>`, you are stating that `res` is of type `Articles`. So it sounds like `results` does not exist on `Articles`. perhaps your interface is incorrectly defined

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: also you're saying that the http observable is returning `Articles`, but your `getAllArticles` function that returns it states that it returns an Array of Articles. So observable type and return type don't seem to be equal.

Comment: Yeah that is the issue. Your json isn't returning `Articles` it is returning a different format. You either need to define that format and pass it in to `this.http.get<YourNewType>()` or use any `this.http.get<any>()`. But with the latter, you lose strict typing.

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt the `map` method returns an array of `Articles` so this should match up.

Comment: Thanks! I changed by this.http.get<any>(), I don't have an error but It's normal to have an Interface IArticles and a class Articles ? (I edited)

Comment: @ElGecko_76 Typically you would use one or the other. Here is angular's [recommendation](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces) on classes/interfaces

Comment: So the code I put in the suggestion is not clean?

Comment: I would consolidate your code to just use the class definition. I would also create a new type for the return (just to get that strict typing back) `export interface MyArticlesResponse { results: {id: number; title: string}[];}` then use `this.http.get<MyArticlesResponse>()`

Comment: Thank you! The goal is to loop in asynchronous to display the results in my template, it is possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161133/discussion-between-llai-and-elgecko-76).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our conversation, you will need to change your map method to access properties that match your json response

```
// service.ts
getAllArticles() : Observable<Articles[]>{
    return this.http.get<GetArticlesResponse[]>(this.urlAllArticles)
        .map(res => {
            return res.map(item => {
                return new Articles(
                    item.id,
                    item.titre
                );
            });
        });
}

// used to strictly type the http return type
export interface GetArticlesResponse {
    id: number;
    titre: string;
}
```

Comment: The Observable<Articles[]> instead of Observable<Articles> is necessary ?

Comment: @ElGecko_76 yep because you are returning an array of `Articles`